# getView from customized ArrayAdapter isn't called

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

For some reasons getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) of my customized ArrayAdapter isn't called and android displays an empty list. I've already Override getCount()

```
public class CEL_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinkedHashMap<RoomItem, LinkedHashMap<ItemType, List<RoomDamage>>>> {

private Context context;
private int resource;
private List<LinkedHashMap<RoomItem, LinkedHashMap<ItemType, List<RoomDamage>>>> elementsFromXMLList;

public CEL_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<LinkedHashMap<RoomItem, LinkedHashMap<ItemType, List<RoomDamage>>>> elementsFromXMLList) {
    super(context, resource, elementsFromXMLList);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.elementsFromXMLList = elementsFromXMLList;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int positionItem = position;
    View view;
    LayoutInflater viewInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView != null)
        view = convertView;
    else
        view = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.etat_piece_item, parent, false);
    {...}
    return view;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.elementsFromXMLList.size();
}
```

And this is how I set Adapter:

```
CEL_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter cel_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter = new CEL_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter(mContext, R.layout.etat_piece_item, elementsFromXMLLinkedHashMap);
            listViewElements.setAdapter(cel_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter);
```

I'm looking for a solution since yesterday, I have read all of the posts on StackOverflow but none match my issue. So I would like to know, if it could come from LinkedHashMap<...>

Edit: this is my layout R.layout.etat_piece_item

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mis2_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="12" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionElement_TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mis_item_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/typeElement_Spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_ab_default"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mis_item_size"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantiteElement_EdiText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mis_item_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etatElement_TextView"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="callChooseEtat"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ent_obervations_val"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mis_item_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="callCameraInList" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoElement_ImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_img" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trouElement_EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/zero"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mis_item_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionElement_TextView"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mis_item_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/stroke_dim"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure there are actually elements in your `elementsFromXMLList`? also, what is the implementation for `getItem` and `getItemId`?

Comment: Yes getCount() was returning 30. But I didn't Override getItem and getItemId, is it necessary ?

Comment: Do you call the notify dataset changed (no idea what exactly it's called since I don't have access to Eclipse right now) on your adapter when you populate the underlying list? Do you "new" the list anywhere instead of clearing and repopulating it? if answer is no to (1) or yes to (2), that's the problem.

Comment: @Guimareshh: overriding it is of course totally allowed (since that method is not final), and makes exactly as much sense as overriding `getCount`

Comment: @njzk2 Oh yes you right for overriding getItem and getItemId, I made a mistake. But unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue to Override these methods.

Comment: is your listview visible? does it have some room to inflate the items?

Comment: @njzk2 yes, moreover I set an header and it's visible. And my List have 30 items.

Comment: can you post the layout `etat_piece_item`?

Comment: Finally I got the answer. The issue come from layout of the activity. I forget to delete scrollView on top of fragment container

Answer (score 0):

It's being called, it's only returning a null value. ConvertView is null for the first getView call, so you have to inflate something (even if its not your first position nothing guarantees that it isnt null) and you dont seem to be inflating anything.

Try this:

```
if(convertView != null)
  view = convertView;
else
  view = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, parent, false);
```

Where R.layout.yourlayout is the layout you want to populate your list with.

Comment: I'm already doing this (it was inside {...}), and I'm sure it's not being called. Indeed, on debug mode getView() isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to inflate view actually instead of using convert view.
Convertview will be not null only when atleast one view is populated inside the array adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class CEL_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LinkedHashMap<RoomItem, LinkedHashMap<ItemType, List<RoomDamage>>>> {

    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private List<LinkedHashMap<RoomItem, LinkedHashMap<ItemType, List<RoomDamage>>>> elementsFromXMLList;

    public CEL_ElementsFromXMLArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<LinkedHashMap<RoomItem, LinkedHashMap<ItemType, List<RoomDamage>>>> elementsFromXMLList) {
        super(context, resource, elementsFromXMLList);

        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.elementsFromXMLList = elementsFromXMLList;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int positionItem = position;
        View view = convertView;
        View v = (View)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(your layout,parent, false);
        // this will make a list item from your layout then insert your data into it's child views

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.elementsFromXMLList.size();
    }
```